# Assertion Failed: '@dropdown.isOpen' is not a valid path

Tags: ubuntu, npm, ember.js, broccolijs

Getting this error when trying to run a web app built in ember:

> ```
> Template Compiler Error (broccoli-persistent-filter:TemplateCompiler) in ember-basic-dropdown/templates/components/basic-dropdown-content.hbs
>
> Assertion Failed: '@dropdown.isOpen' is not a valid path. ('ember-basic-dropdown/templates/components/basic-dropdown-content.hbs' @ L2:C6)
> ```

Using:

- ember-cli: 2.18.2
- node: 10.15.2
- os: linux x64
- ember-basic-dropdown: 5.8.0

[Full Error Log](https://pastebin.com/SqmtPe85)

Comment: In order to answer this we need to see your component code.

Comment: It looks like the latest version of ember-basic-dropdown is 3.0.1. Can you check the version again? Also for Ember 2.x, you will need to use version 1.x of ember-basic-dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this page

https://github.com/cibernox/ember-basic-dropdown/issues/485

This will give you an answer. You need to update the latest CLI version.